# Jest test failing because of mismatch in quotes

Tags: node.js, jestjs

Testing is failing because of mismatch in quotes.

[image: failing test error]

Similar SO issue: [JSET test object does not match - quotes issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60974034/jset-test-object-does-not-match-quotes-issue)

Comment: Please show what you tried, your data, and some more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like string is expected what is received is actually an array. Try to stringify it